# perl script- to read many values from xml file

Tags: perl

how to read the multiple values from XML file using perl script? 
i have the xml file like:

```
<Provisioning>
<Appliance>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <SiteID></SiteID>
        <IPAddress>10.52.32.230</IPAddress>
</Appliance>
<Appliance>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <SiteID></SiteID>
        <IPAddress>10.52.32.530</IPAddress>
</Appliance>
<Appliance>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <SiteID></SiteID>
        <IPAddress>10.52.32.730</IPAddress>
</Appliance>...
</Provisioning>
```

and i have written the code like:

```
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $peermas = $xml->XMLin($masapplications);
print "file contents: $peermas \n";
print Dumper($peermas);
@masipaddr =+ $peermas->{Appliance}->{IPAddress};      #{Provisioning}->{Appliance}->{IPAddress};
print "The MAS ip: @masipaddr \n";
```

i am very new to perl script and my code can read only one IP address not the remaining 2.
so what should i do in this case?? please reply soon... 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Using XML::Simple without specifying any options will usually lead to pain down the line.  Refer to this article on 'strict mode' for more details: http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=218480

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have all info you need in your `$peermas`. But if you need array of your IP addressed you may use:

```
my @massipaddr = map { $_->{IPAddress} } @{ $peermas->{Appliance} };
```

This map iterate on array of hashes `$peermas->{Appliance}` and push each IPAddress from it into `@massipaddr`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Simple;

my $xml = join '', <DATA>;

my $peermas = XMLin($xml);

foreach (@{$peermas->{Appliance}}) {
  print $_->{IPAddress}. "\n";
}

__DATA__
<Provisioning>
<Appliance>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <SiteID></SiteID>
        <IPAddress>10.52.32.230</IPAddress>
</Appliance>
<Appliance>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <SiteID></SiteID>
        <IPAddress>10.52.32.530</IPAddress>
</Appliance>
<Appliance>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <SiteID></SiteID>
        <IPAddress>10.52.32.730</IPAddress>
</Appliance>...
</Provisioning>
```